# LifeCycle of onChange in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a simple react application, now I am working on an element that can take the user's input. I have been very curious about the order of the execution of line of code inside the onChange() function. So I added a little print statement to see how exactly things are changed.

Here's my code

```
function CreateReview() {

    
    const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title:'',
    content:''
})

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('render');
 },[input])

function handleChange(event){
    const {name, value} =event.target;

    console.log(1)
    setInput(prevInput=>
        {
            console.log(2)
            return{
                 ...prevInput, //...prevInput is to reserve the last Input
                 [name]: value //name is dynamic, "title" then setTitle, "content" then setContent.
                
            }
        }
    )
    console.log(3)
    console.log(event.target);
}

function handleClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(input);
}

return <div className = "container">
    <h1>Create Review</h1>
    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <input onChange={handleChange} name="title" value={input.title} autoComplete="off" className = 'form-control' placeholder="Your Name"></input>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <textarea onChange={handleChange} name="content" value={input.content} autoComplete="off" className = 'form-control' placeholder="Review Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-large btn-info">Add Note</button>
    </form>
</div>
}


export default CreateReview;
```

And here's the output console

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKg4f.png)

I wonder why it goes 1,3,2. is there any reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly go to react document to read more about `how state works in react`.

As far as your concerned `useState or setState` are the async events, so whenever you are try to call them it will execute later rather do synchronously(line by line).